# How to get values of functions in an array for a range of values of variables?

Tags: numpy

```
from sympy.abc import *
import sympy as s
import numpy as n
z = n.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
g = n.array([11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
x = n.array([z+g,z-g,z*g])
```

I want to get `x` for a range of values of `z` and `g`. `z` and `g` are arrays. So if both contain 10 elements, should I get 100 results?

Comment: _"z ang g are arrays"'_ - not in the code you gave us, there they're `Symbol`s. Which is it?

Comment: my question edited. now please help me

Answer (score 0):

In the code you use `z`and `g`are symbols, not arrarys. Just define them as arrays:

```
z = n.linspace(0,1,10) #create the arrays
g = n.linspace(0,1,10) 
g = g.reshape(-1,1) # reshape g, such that numpy broadcasts them
x=n.array([z+g,z-g,z*g])
```

Numpy knows many different ways to multiply/add/... all entries of several array with all entries of another. E.g. `dot,outer` etc.

Two other remarks:
I would use `import numpy as np`, as "everybody does this your code will be more easy to read for others
I would not use `from anything import *`, as this might mask builtin variables.

Comment: `from sympy.abc import *` defines `z` and `g` (the whole alphabet) as `sympy.symbols`.  So the `z,g=s.symbols('z g')` line isn't needed.  It's probably used in `sympy` tutorials as a convenience.  But as your answer shows, `sympy` doesn't help with this problem.

Comment: if i want to get a text file with columns z,g and curresponding value of x, what should i do?

Comment: @Shareef Sorry what, do you want? Can you give an example of how the txt file should look like (maybe with only few entries). Should it contain variables or numbers?
In case you just want to save `x` to a txt file use [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: i want three columns. first  two columns are z and g. third column is the curresponding x.  For eg. if z=1, g=2. i shoulg get 1 in first column, 2 in second column and (3,-1,2) in third colmn.

Comment: Is it important, that the last colum contains lists?

Comment: Actually, my aim is to find the set of values (z,g) for which each element in x is minimum. Then i want to substitute those values and add them to get a number which is the third column ( list not needed ).

Comment: @Sharee Then you don't really need a txt file, right? Furthermore my code should work. Use `np.amin` afterwards to find the minimum. Note that the minimum will not occur for all entries at the same time.

Comment: Actually, my aim is to find the set of values (z,g) for which each element in x is minimum. Then i want to substitute those values and add them to get a number which is the third column ( list not needed ).     Excuse me if i repeat, i had edited my comment

Comment: if i use np.amin, i will get min of the values. but i want to get (z,g) for which 'each element' in x is a minimum and then substitute them to get x that contains three numbers. then add those three numbers to get a number which should be my third column for curresponding (z,g).